# How to Parse text file using SSIS Script Component with Complex and Varied Data

Tags: c#, sql-server, regex, ssis

I have a text file that holds data based on a series of tags.  Tag A represents a column with CRLF delimiter, Tag B is a separate column with a semi-colon delimiter, and Tag C contains values delimited by under scores and CRLF delimiters.  I've created a C# Script component with output columns for each tag.

Sample Data for each Tag:

```
Tag A varchar(10) A123456789 
TagB varchar (50) cdw5w3464353
Tag C varchar(max) ***;User_____Date______Value;User123_____6/3/15_____3366cde;
```

Do I use RegEx for identification of each tag value?  Or is there another way to handle this scenario?  Note that the tags repeat for each entry to be loaded into the SQL Server destination.  Also, note that only some of the tags are needed, extraneous text values in the records can be disregarded.

Comment: Can you add some sample data? And SQL table/column info?

Comment: Yes, I've updated the question with sample data.

Comment: I used to wrestle with this type of structure when I started my IT career over 20 years ago.  Who would've thought that in 2015 there would still be "genius" devs kindly producing a unique mess like this, to keep us all gainfully employed ... I love this industry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try to keep the Script component as simple as possible - just splitting the input rows into separate text files, perhaps adding Row Numbers or similar to keep track of sets of rows.  I would use Strings.Split to chop each Tag C row into separate columns, e.g. all the Date values go in column #2, with a single heading row showing "Date" in column #2.

Then I would use the SSIS Flat File Source component (in a subsequent Data Flow Task) to load the data from the separate text files.  That Data Flow can ignore any unwanted columns.

Comment: Since the file contains multiple instances of each tag, do I write each tag into a separate text file?

Comment: I imagine so - as long as that leaves you with consistent rows (same number of columns, same delimiters) within each file.